# OpenLayers: cancel dragging

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How to cancel feature dragging by Esc key or right mouse button in OpenLayers? I can handle removing/restoring objects, but cannot understand when and where it should be done.

Comment: By cancel do you mean unselect the feature and have it remain at whatever position it is currently at or unselect and reset the feature to the position it had before the drag started?

Comment: The second. The 1st looks like normal behavior when drag is successfully ending.

Comment: What openlayers version are you using (so that I can provide example code)?

Comment: Version 2.13.1. I've been searching a little and it seems that there is no interaction with keys on DragFeature control. Currently I've made it by simply handling jquery's key event and put the logic here